# Need to have a pie chart representation of data in an excel file using Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, charts

Need to have a pie chart representation of data in an excel file using Python.
I have a column as 
|**Values**|
|Yes|
|No|
|Yes|
|Yes|
|No|

I want to have above values(Yes / No) represented as a pie chart on the basis of counts of their occurrence with the help of Python. Please suggest.

EDITED:
One thing that needs to be denoted i.e. Counts of Yes and Counts of No. (Better if we can have that in %). Currently it is drawing a pie chart but no counts. I am attaching a screenshot for reference.[image]

Answer (score 1):

To read the data, check out [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).
To get the counts of Yes/No you can use [pd.Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)
You can plot a pie chart directly from pandas using [pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html)

Here is a quick example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Replace below with pd.read_excel() to get your data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No']})
counts = df['Value'].value_counts()
counts.plot.pie(autopct='%.2f%%')
plt.show()
```

Pandas is using Matplotlib underneath, see the docs on [matplotlib.pyplot.pie](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) for more details on arguments etc.

[Here](https://medium.com/@kvnamipara/a-better-visualisation-of-pie-charts-by-matplotlib-935b7667d77f) is a nice article on Pie chart design

Comment: Great! Its working.

Only one thing needs to be denoted i.e. Counts of Yes and Counts of No. (Better if we can have that in %). Currently it is drawing a pie chart but no counts. I am attaching a screenshot for reference.

Comment: Updated answer, the documentation is always a good place to look if you want to see what you can do with a particular function, there is detail in both Pandas and Matplotlib on how to use pie charts